# Design patterns for runtime object creation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, runtime, factory-pattern

I have a class which facilitates the discovery of `HID` devices, when a device is detected an `event` is raised and subsequently detected by another class which will be ultimately responsible for the creation of an `object` to represent the `HID` device.  The `creation class` raises an `event` of its own with the newly created `HID` object.

With this in mind I have a couple of design queries:

> 1)
>   I have done some research into the "*best practices"* with regards to the creation of an unknown number or type of object at runtime for which the `Abstract Factory` design pattern features frequently in the results.  Does the `Abstract Factory` design pattern fit the scenario I have, or is there something else I should be doing?
>
> 2)
>   The `HidFinder` class raises an event to notify those interested (mostly the `HidCreator` class) that a device has been discovered.  The `HidCreator` class then raises an event containing the newly created `HID` device.  This seems like the correct method, however, confirmation either way would be appreciated.

Below is a dumbed down example of the code in question.

```
public class HidFinder
{
    public event EventHandler<HidFoundArgs> HidFoundHandler;

    private void DeviceAdded(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnHidFoundHandler(new HidFoundArgs());
    }

    protected virtual void OnHidFoundHandler(HidFoundArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<HidFoundArgs> handler = this.HidFoundHandler;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}

public class HidCreator
{
    private readonly HidFinder hidFinder;

    public event EventHandler<IHidDevice> HidDeviceCreatedHandler;

    public HidCreator(HidFinder hidFinder)
    {
        this.hidFinder = hidFinder;
        this.hidFinder.HidFoundHandler += HidFinderOnHidFoundHandler;
    }

    private void HidFinderOnHidFoundHandler(object sender, HidFoundArgs hidFoundArgs)
    {
        // Create a new HID
        var newHidDevice = Factory.CreateMethod();
        OnHidDeviceCreatedHandler(newHidDevice);
    }

    protected virtual void OnHidDeviceCreatedHandler(IHidDevice e)
    {
        EventHandler<IHidDevice> handler = this.HidDeviceCreatedHandler;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It generally looks as good design, but I would make two changes:

1. `Factory` seems like some global object, it would be better to use Dependency Injection, for better unit testing for example.
2. Change `Factory.CreateMethod` to use parameters, as we don't know what exact implementation of `IHidDevice` will be created and if we won't need some additional info from `HidFoundArgs`

Code after changes:

```
public class HidCreator
{
    private readonly HidFinder hidFinder;
    private readonly IHidDeviceFactory factory;

    public event EventHandler<IHidDevice> HidDeviceCreatedHandler;

    public HidCreator(IHidDeviceFactory factory, HidFinder hidFinder)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.hidFinder = hidFinder;
        this.hidFinder.HidFoundHandler += HidFinderOnHidFoundHandler;
    }

    private void HidFinderOnHidFoundHandler(object sender, HidFoundArgs hidFoundArgs)
    {
        // Create a new HID
        var newHidDevice = factory.Create(HidFoundArgs.ToCreationParameters(hidFoundArgs));
        OnHidDeviceCreatedHandler(newHidDevice);
    }

    protected virtual void OnHidDeviceCreatedHandler(IHidDevice e)
    {
        EventHandler<IHidDevice> handler = this.HidDeviceCreatedHandler;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}

public interface IHidDeviceFactory
{
    IHidDevice Create(HidCreationParameters parameters);
    ...
}

public class HidCreationParameters
{
   ...
}

public class HidFoundArgs
{
    public static HidCreationParameters ToCreationParameters(HidFoundArgs args)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```